# Node query empty data

Tags: node.js

Well, I made a simple query that makes me able to search users by name or email... But I need to make it search for these queries only when they are defined. For example, I can have missing queries in URL or empty queries in URL. But I don't know how to fix it.

This is my controller

```
/**
 * GET /admin/users/:page
 * Find users
 */
exports.findUsers = (req, res, next) => {
  const perPage = 13
  const page = Number(req.params.page) || 1
  var query = {
    id: req.query.id,
    "profile.firstname": req.query.firstname,
    "profile.lastname": req.query.lastname,
    "profile.location": req.query.location,
    "profile.status": req.query.status,
    email: req.query.email
  }
  console.log(query)
  User
    .find(query)
    .skip((perPage * page) - perPage)
    .limit(perPage)
    .exec(function (err, users) {
      User.countDocuments().exec(function (err, count) {
        if (err) return next(err)
        res.render('admin/users', {
          layout: "admin",
          users: users,
          active: {
            users: true
          },
          current: page,
          pages: Math.ceil(count / perPage),
          helpers,
          pagesArr: Array.from(Array(((Math.ceil(count / perPage)))).keys()).map(i => 1 + i),
          pagination: core.pagination(page, (Math.ceil(count / perPage))),
        })
      })
    })
};
```

And this is my view

```
<form method="GET" class="main-search-form" action="/admin/users/1">
            <input type="text" name="id" placeholder="ID">
            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Firstname">
            <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Lastname">
            <input type="text" name="location" placeholder="Country">
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
            <input type="text" name="status" placeholder="Status">
            <input type="submit" value="Search">
        </form>
        <table class="main-table"> // PRINTED USERS // </table>
```

For example i can have

Filled query

```
http://localhost:8080/admin/users/1?id=132465798&firstname=Geroge&lastname=Bush&location=USA&email=bush%40bush.com&status=1
```

Or just one query filled

```
http://localhost:8080/admin/users/1?id=&firstname=George&lastname=&location=&email=&status=
```

or just

```
http://localhost:8080/admin/users/1
```

Problem is that when is only one query filled it gives zero results because it's looking for users with no last name or location with are required by registration. And without query it gaves me no result too because queries are undefined. It only finds user when everything is filled.
Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can populate your `query` variable conditionally on the existence of props in your GET request.

Since some of the keys used by your query differ from the keys sent in your `req.query` request, you could define an object for each possible key that maps the key in the request to the desired key in the query.

Then assign the key on your `query` variable for each key that exists in the request, using these request => query key mappings. Like this:

```
var query = {};

const possibleQueryProps = [
  {
    "key": "id",
    "queryKey": "id"
  },
  {
    "key": "firstname",
    "queryKey": "profile.firstname"
  },
  {
    "key": "lastname",
    "queryKey": "profile.lastname"
  },
  {
    "key": "location",
    "queryKey": "profile.location"
  },
  {
    "key": "status",
    "queryKey": "status"
  }
];   

possibleQueryProps.forEach(prop => { 
    if(req.query[prop.key]) {
        query[prop.queryKey] = req.query[prop.key]; 
    } 
});

// run the query with your query obj
```

For instance, if req.query is 
`{ "id": 1, "firstname": "test" }`,
you will get back `{ "id": 1, "profile.firstname": "test" }`

Comment: First, I want to thank for your effort but we probably misunderstood each other. This query should find users like search and those inputs should not be required. Like u can search only by the first name or only by the last name or only by mail... Or by two like first name and last name............ This is simple GET search. But thanks again for your effort.

Comment: Hi @Juraj -- my apologies! I misunderstood your question...thank you for clarifying. I have edited my answer significantly to show what I believe you were asking about.

Comment: Wou thank you very much just little edited needed but it works :) 
if(req.query.hasOwnProperty(prop.key))  should be if(req.query[prop.key])

Comment: Oops, good catch! I updated the answer. Glad it works for you.